# Incorrect Values in a Simple Chunk

Tags: c++, return-value

This is rather odd, but I have this single little chunk of code that I'm using to count how many of each suit there are in a hand. However, Clubs and Hearts always return ridiculously outrageous and obviously wrong results. Diamonds and Spades are always correct. What am I missing here?

```
  int numClubs, numHearts, numDiamonds, numSpades = 0;

      // Iterate through all the cards in the
      // player's hand, incrementing the counters
      // if they are a given suit.
      for (int i = 0; i < m_numCards; i++){
        if ((m_cards[i]->getSuit()) == Card::Clubs)
          numClubs++;
        else if ((m_cards[i]->getSuit()) == Card::Hearts)
          numHearts++;
        else if ((m_cards[i]->getSuit()) == Card::Diamonds)
          numDiamonds++;
        else
          numSpades++;
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration only initializes `numSpades`. The other variables have undefined values, that is, whatever happened to be in memory. Try this:

```
int numClubs = 0, numHearts = 0, numDiamonds = 0, numSpades = 0;
```

Diamonds just happened to have a zero value which is why it appeared to work correctly.

Comment: @swingonaspiral You're not the first to make that mistake and you certainly won't be the last. :)